# Which is the right sentence to compare multiple objects with different properties?

Tags: grammaticality, comparisons

I'm writing a scientific paper in which there is a statement on the comparison of multiple objects with different properties. 
Actually, I would like to compare among A with P1, A with P2, B, and C. 
I would like to avoid the duplication of A.

I have two options by now:

- We compare A with P1 and with P2, B, and C.
- We compare A with P1/P2, B and C.

What's the right option? Or they are both wrong.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we compare the two A's (P1 and P2), B, and C among themselves ...

By comparing the A's (P1 and P2), B, and C among themselves ...

By comparing the A (both P1 and P2), B, and C among themselves ...

Comment: I see that the parentheses are suitable. However, P1 and P2 are properties which need not belong to A. Is it still make sense to use A's instead of A?

Comment: I'm merely suggesting some options. The apostrophe helps form the plural: A (singular), A's (plural). "The A's" means "both A's." Since the parenthesized values are followed by a comma, it is clear that both pertain to the A in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I would like the emphasize the objects A, B and C, so I could not use the A's.

Comment: How about now? ...

Comment: I think the third sentence is the most closest to my meaning. However, the readers may perceive that "the A (both P1 and P2)" means A with P1 and P2, where P1 and P2 won't exist simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

The way you stated it in your question sounds best. 
"compare among A with P1, A with P2, B, and C."
But that might create a psychological weighting toward A.

ABC do not always need to come in that order.  You can use the conjunction to your advantage.

As we compare among C, B, A with P1, and with P2 ...